# regexp_extract function - Spark scala getting error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here are the sample records

```
SYSTEM, paid18.26 toward test
sys, paid $861.82 toward your
L, paid $1119.00toward your
```

I need to extract the data between paid and toward. I have written the statement like below and I am not getting the output

```
withColumn("message_comment_txt_amount",regexp_extract(col("message_comment_txt"),"(?i)paid\\s+(.*?)\\s+(?i)toward",1))
```

I am not getting the desired

Expected Output

```
18.26 
861.82 
1119.00
```

Please let me know where the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the amount always come in between strings "paid" and "toward"

```
 val amount = df.withColumn(
      "amount",
      regexp_extract(col("message_comment_txt"), "^paid(.*)toward.*", 1)
    )
```

The above snippet adds a new column amount to the dataset/df. It doesn't check / replace the $ symbol though. That can be replaced in the next step if this works fine as expected in all your cases.